# Root field of $x^3+x^2+x+2$ over $\mathbb{Z}_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

> Find the root field of $p(x)=x^3+x^2+x+2$ over $\mathbb{Z}_3$.

$p(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_3$ by direct substitution of $x=0,1,2$.

Suppose $u$ is a root of $p(x)$. Then $[\mathbb{Z}_3(u):\mathbb{Z}_3]=3$ since the minimum polynomial has degree $3$.

Now, $p(x)=(x-u)q(x)$, where $q(x)=x^2+(u+1)x+(u^2+u+1)$.

Now I want to show that $q(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_3(u)[x]$. I need to do direct substitution of the $27$ elements in $\mathbb{Z}_3(u)$. Is there an easier way?

Comment: I'm guessing that by "root field" you actually mean "splitting field"= a (or the) minimal extension field that contains all the roots of $\;p(x)\;$ ...?

Comment: @DonAntonio That's correct, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\ q(x)\,$ has discriminant $ = u = (u^2-u)^2$

Comment: I understand the discriminant is $u$, but I don't understand how $(u^2-u)^2$ comes, or how it helps.

Comment: Well, it helps a lot @JJBeck, since this answer shows the discriminant is a square in $\;\Bbb Z_3(u)\;$ so its roots are in that field...

Comment: @DonAntonio But I don't understand why $(u^2-u)^2=u$, even in $\mathbb{Z}_3$

Comment: @JJBeck $\ \ (x^2-x)^2-x =  x(x^3+x^2+x\color{#c00}{-1})\ \ $ and $\ \color{#c00}{-1\equiv 2 \pmod3}$

Comment: Okay, so I was wrong, and it fact $q(x)$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}_3(u)[x]$

Comment: @JJ Beck, we have

$$u^3+u^2+u+2=0\implies \color{red}{u^3=-u^2-u-2\;\;(**)}$$

and from here

$$ (u^2-u)^2=u^4-2u^3+u^2\stackrel{(**)}=-u^3-u^2-2u-2u^3+u^2-2u=u\pmod 3$$